# How to tell which Python env is faster

Tags: python, performance, benchmarking

I have a Jupyter notebook running locally and one running on a remote server.

I made the server because I was concerned that my local was too slow.

After playing around on the server, I feel like it's faster but I'm not sure.

How can I measure the difference in speed between my local notebook server and the remote notebook server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could always time your script on both the server and your local notebook.

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
main()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```